# running quickly application using pycharm

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, canonical-quickly

I was wondering how I could run a `quickly` application using `pycharm`. The way which I would hope to do it is instead of saying:

```
$ quickly run
```

In the terminal, I would Hope that I could instead just say something like

```
$ python bin/myapp.py
```

(That is the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205403/quickly-with-python-3-or-how-to-start-a-quickly-app-without-quickly-run), but it doesn't seem to work for me). That would mean I wouldn't have to do any weird setup on the python interpreters. However, if I need to, I can adjust `pycharm's` settings.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: At the moment I have a **really** dodgy solution of simply writing
import os; os.system("quickly run")

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Well, looking at the steps in the link: yes, I have broken down the problem. From there, I found the 2 bits I couldn't solve were to run a python script which would run my program or to run a bash command as the interpreter in pycharm.
Yes, I have looked at pycharm's online documentation, and I can't work out how to add a bash command as an interpreter. I looked at the man pages for quickly, since I couldn't find much documentation online, but they didn't say anything about it.
My googling didn't provide any results.
And the sample code isn't for running it, it's for creating the application.

Comment: add the comments to your question. your current code helps, but isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer when looking to add an interpreter. go to run > edit configuration.

I don't know if this is necessary, but I just set the working directory for the project interpreter to be the application one (it might do this by default).

Down below that, there is a place with a + icon above it. Click there to add an external tool.

The necessary settings for that tool is program: "quickly" and parameters: "run" (both without quotes).

Again, I'm not sure if it's nessecary to set the working directory here, but I did it just to be safe.

Comment: ok, after looking at that, it appears that stdout from the application can't be seen. It may have something to do with the "output filters" in the external tool.

Comment: I see stdout from the external tool. The only difference I did is I specified `/bin/bash` as Program, and `-c quickly run` as Parameters.

Comment: Also, PyCharm needs you to specify a script to run (when you create the run configuration). Specifying `/dev/null` works well :)